# Which electronic circuit simulator is working wrong?

Tags: resistors, simulation, voltage-divider

I ran a simulation of the same circuit on three simulators and one gave me different values.

Which simulator working right and which wrong?

[Falstad](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/):

[image]

[EveryCircuit](https://everycircuit.com/app):

[image]

[PartSim](https://www.partsim.com/simulator#):

[image]

Comment: In the first circuit you're measuring the ground, use a voltmeter instead of a wire.

Comment: Thanks. I think you right. It seems that the voltmeter shows the correct value.

Comment: I fix it for you https://tinyurl.com/23f5xww7

Comment: `simulation of the same circuit` ... no, not the same circuit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try looking at things in detail: -

[image]